# Migrating from TFS to VSTS with TFVC

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

My usecase:

1. Currently have TFS 2012 (on Prem)
2. Want to move to VSTS
3. Want to migrate only the SourceCode with history, don't need any workitems, etc.

Questions:
1. What are the tools I can use?
2. Is it mandatory to upgrade to TFS 2018 first before migrating to VSTS

Comment: Yes, you have to upgrade from tfs 2012 to latest version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview?view=vsts). You can download the migration guide for help. I assume this is a corporate account, contacting microsoft won't hurt the pocket

Comment: What's result if you try it with OpsHub?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate the source code only then you have 3 options.

1. The MS recommended route is to upgrade to TFS 2018 and then use the Database import feature of VSTS. This is the only way to keep using TFVC and keep the full history in tact.
2. You could use [OpsHub](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) however this comes with limitations as it will "replay" the history so the changeset history will reflect the time of the migration rather than the time of the original check-in. Also if you have multiple team projects then you might need to pay for the tool.
3. If you only want the code and you are happy considering changing version control systems from TFVC to Git then this might be the simplest option. You could use [Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) essentially you would clone the TFS (TFVC) repository to a local Git repository. At this point you would have a full "copy" of version control including history and branches, but in Git instead of TFVC. You could then push this up to VSTS, the only "downside" is that you would now be using Git rather than TFVC, Git is good, but different so you will want to think about that.

Comment: For option 1, do notice: TFS 2018 also requires MS SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1), which can be quite a big move.

Comment: @RobBos that's a good point, there will be a SQL upgrade and potentially a Windows upgrade required if the current host OS is older than Windows Server 2012